How to access Parameter Estimates?
I have builded a regression model with ols_step_both_aic() and I would like to access the "Parameter Estimates" of the model to sort the selected variables accoridng to their Std. Beta or Sig value:

How can I obtain a dataframe with the Estimates?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
